# Log-linear analysis of transition matrices using R

Tags: r, log-linear, demography

I have some demographic transition matrices that I want to compare using a log linear analysis, but am having some trouble with model construction in R.  I have read through several tutorials on log-linear, but they don't seem to cover my specific case.

I have two transition matrices, where the column represents state at time $t$ and the row represents fate at time $(t+1)$.  I want to first compare the overall matrices, then decompose so that I can look at each of the individual initial states (as presented in Hal Caswell's book Matrix Population Models, p. 329).

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
install.packages("MASS")
library(MASS)

mat1 = matrix(c(495, 90, 1, 0, 0, 0, 361, 91, 221, 30, 6, 0, 0, 
                2, 0, 13, 36, 17, 4, 0, 4, 0, 1, 6, 18, 19, 1, 
                0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 8, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 5, 4, 0),nrow=7,ncol=6,byrow = FALSE)
mat2 = matrix(c(496, 91, 0, 0, 0, 0, 364, 96, 219, 9, 3, 
                2, 0, 12, 3, 35, 22, 11, 5, 0, 4, 2, 15, 8, 8, 
                12, 0, 4, 0, 6, 11, 3, 7, 7, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                7, 1),nrow=7,ncol=6,byrow = FALSE)

rownames(mat1) = c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","Dead")
rownames(mat2) = c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","Dead")
colnames(mat1) = c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6")
colnames(mat2) = c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6")

mat1 = as.data.frame(mat1)
mat2 = as.data.frame(mat2)

f_CrossTabToTable = function(dat){
  r = nrow(dat)
  out = data.frame(State=factor(),Fate=factor(),Value=numeric())
  for (i in 1:r){
    val = dat[i,]
    row = rep(rownames(dat[i,]),ncol(dat))
    col = colnames(dat)
    tmp = data.frame(col,row,t(val))
    names(tmp) = names(out)
    out = rbind(out,tmp)
  }
  return(out)
}

m1 = f_CrossTabToTable(mat1)
m2 = f_CrossTabToTable(mat2)

Year1 = rep(as.factor("Year1"),nrow(m1))
Year2 = rep(as.factor("Year2"),nrow(m1))

m1 = cbind(Year1,m1)
m2 = cbind(Year2,m2)
names(m1)[1] = "Year"
names(m2)[1] = "Year"

dat = rbind(m1,m2) ## combine
dat2 = xtabs(Value ~ .,dat) ##X create table

fm = loglm(~ Year * State * Fate,data=dat2) ### full model with interactions
fm1 = update(fm, ~ . -(Year:State + State:Fate + Year:Fate + Year:State:Fate),data=dat2 ) ### model without any interaction terms
fm2 = update(fm, ~ . -(Year:Fate + Year:State:Fate),data=dat2 ) ### remove all Year by Fate interaction terms

anova(fm,fm2)
```

Is this correct and the appropriate model formation?  I basically added a variable ("Year") for each matrix and removed any Year:Fate interactions.